# Docker container name not resolved as DNS for overlay network not reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've an application composed of a kafka producer and another kafka consumer. I'm trying to deploy it on a Docker swarm on AWS with mutli-host networking enabled. Kafka container is created by the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
kafka:
  image: spotify/kafka
  environment:
    ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"
    - "9092:9092"
```

This is how I run the containers for the different components:

```
> docker-compose -f helloworld_kafka.yml --x-networking up -d
Creating network "helloworld"
...
> docker run -d --name helloworld_producer_1 --net helloworld -it elsoufy/myimage ./myexec -role producer -queue helloworld_kafka_1:9092
> docker run -d --name helloworld_consumer_1 --net helloworld -it elsoufy/myimage ./myexec -role consumer -queue helloworld_kafka_1:9092
```

When I check the `/etc/hosts`of `helloworld_kafka_1` I found entries for both `helloworld_server_1` and `helloworld_consumer_1`:

```
10.0.0.2    kafka_container_id
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
10.0.0.3    helloworld_server_1
10.0.0.3    helloworld_server_1.helloworld
10.0.0.4    helloworld_consumer_1
10.0.0.4    helloworld_consumer_1.helloworld
```

But when I check the logs of the latter I realize that they failed to connect to kafka. I see the following:

```
> docker logs consumer_container_id
2015/11/27 16:05:52 Kafka brokers: helloworld_kafka_1:9092
2015/11/27 16:05:52 Failed to start consuming dial tcp: lookup kafka_container_id on 10.10.0.2:53: no such host
```

It looks like When `10.10.0.2`is the DNS (port `53`) used by containers to resolve name and that it's not reachable. When I inspect the network of any nodes I cann't find this address, and it's not in the range of the `helloworld` overlay network. How I can make this DNS reachable? any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You should re-word this so there is a question clearly stated. Port 53 is DNS, so a DNS lookup probably failed.

Comment: thanks @taco for the suggestion, I modified the last paragraph as well as the title. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Try forcing your own DNS with `docker run --dns="1.2.3.4" [foo...]`

Comment: x-networking is dead, Jim.   Are you upgraded to current versions?

Comment: I'd try putting everything in a version 2 or 3 compose file, then troubleshoot from there.    Hard to tell with this half compose, half manual.